# Why am I getting the error message name 'datestr' is not defined? Python 2.7

Tags: python, matplotlib

So datestr() is supposed to convert a number into a date. But I keep getting this Name error message. Am I not loading the correct module. I have searched the Matplotlib documenation but do not see any specific module that must be imported.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator,\
        DayLocator, MONDAY
    from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc, candlestick_ohlc
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    import pandas.io.data as web
    from datetime import date
    import matplotlib

    date = 731613

    print datestr(date)
    #NameError: name 'datestr' is not defined
```

Comment: What makes you think this is a built-in python function? Sounds more like matlab to me. In python you would use something from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) or some wrappers in pandas/numpy/matplotlib.

Comment: In all of the examples used  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html I don't see where they importa a certain module. I have already imported some I plan to use.

Comment: Why are you referring to matlab's docs when using python? You know that these are two different languages/environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I was not using the correct function. I did a search on the problem and I ran into the soltution I tried above the correct format is below.

```
from datetime import date
dte = 731613
print date.fromordinal(dte)
#out put is >> 2004-02-02 
#          (Year, Month, day)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the function `mathplotlib.dates.num2date()`. From there you can convert to a string with `str()` or `strftime()`:

```
>>> from matplotlib.dates import num2date
>>> num2date(731613)
datetime.datetime(2004, 2, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x7f64861fa5d0>)
>>> print(num2date(731613))
2004-02-02 00:00:00+00:00
>>> str(num2date(731613))
'2004-02-02 00:00:00+00:00'
```